# Why does clang-tidy's modernize-use-emplace miss this warning?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

a.cpp:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<pair<int, int>> a;
    a.push_back(make_pair(1, 2)); //caught

    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> b(1);
    b[0].push_back(make_pair(1, 2)); //not caught

    return 0;
}
```

clang-tidy -config="{Checks: 'modernize-use-emplace'}" a.cpp

```
a.cpp:6:4: warning: use emplace_back instead of push_back [modernize-use-emplace]
        a.push_back(make_pair(1, 2)); //caught
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     ~
          emplace_back
```

clang-tidy --version

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 14.0.6
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: skylake
```

[clang-tidy wiki](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize/use-emplace.html)

Comment: You might have found a bug.  File it on clang-tidy's bug tracker.

Comment: ok, let's see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/57392

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: This behavior is due to [bug 56721](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56721) in `clang-tidy`.

Long answer, based on [my comment](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56721#issuecomment-1229912915) on that bug:

The bug relates to how `reference` is declared in the container.  That in turn causes `clang-tidy` to not realize that the return value of the accessor is an instance of a relevant container.

The core of `UseEmplaceCheck.cpp` is:

```
  auto CallPushBack = cxxMemberCallExpr(
      hasDeclaration(functionDecl(hasName("push_back"))),
      on(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasAnyName(SmallVector<StringRef, 5>(
          ContainersWithPushBack.begin(), ContainersWithPushBack.end()))))));
```

Using the example from the question, the following simplified matcher (which can be passed to `clang-query`) will report the non-nested case, as expected:

```
  cxxMemberCallExpr(
    hasDeclaration(functionDecl(hasName("push_back"))),
    on(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("std::vector"))))
  )
```

Reports:

```
  vector<pair<int, int>> a;
  a.push_back(make_pair(1, 2)); //caught
```

However, to get it to match the nested case (when compiling with GCC-9.3.0 headers), it must be changed to:

```
  cxxMemberCallExpr(
    hasDeclaration(functionDecl(hasName("push_back"))),
    on(hasType(namedDecl(hasName("::__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>::value_type"))))
  )
```

Reports:

```
  vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> b(1);
  b[0].push_back(make_pair(1, 2)); //not caught
```

That is, the type is no longer a `cxxRecordDecl`, and its name is a long template-id.  That template-id is derived from the code used to declare `std::vector::reference` in the headers.  It should be semantically equivalent to `std::pair<int, int>`, but that equivalence is evidently obscured from `clang-tidy` here.